# Is there a way to monitor the communication between ActiveX control and the server?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, networking, activex

If I understand it correctly, ActiveX control is a COM component that is invoked by the IE.
In my situation, the ActiveX control is invoking some *.asmx service on server.

So is there any tool that can monitor this communication? I know HttpWatch can monitor everyting on wire, is there any other more **user-friendly** option? Like HttpWatch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean programmatically? If not, maybe Fiddler could help: http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Is Fiddler able to do that? I remember it is implemented as a browser proxy. Anyway, I will double check and get back later.